# How to call function after submit button clicked

Tags: hooks, 7

```
$nid = db_insert('tennis_vana')
  ->fields(array(   'firstname' => $first,   'lastname' => $last   ))
  ->execute(); 

unset($form); 
$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE; 

drupal_set_message("you data has been saved");

$details=project_list1();
```

this is not working. My requirement is, I want to call and display information from after submit.

Comment: could you explain a little more? Question doesnot seem clear.

Comment: function firstest_menu()
{

return $items;
}
function firstest_form($form_state)
{
//code 
return $form;
}
function firstest_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
$nid = db_insert('tennis_vana')
->fields(array(
  'firstname' => $first,
  'lastname' => $last
 ))
->execute();
 unset($form); 
       $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
drupal_set_message("you data has been saved");

$details=project_list1();//here i want to call following functions.

}
function project_list1() {
  //code
  return $output;
}

Comment: You can call project_list() in submit. Are you sure it is returning some $output ? Have you tried calling this function other place than submit ?

Comment: yes..i have tried.

Comment: yes,i have tried..........function project_list1() {
  $header = array('ID', 'Type', 'Name');
  $data = array();

  # set the database table
  $query = db_select('tennis_vana', 'p');

  # configure the query
  $query->fields('p', array('firstname','lastname'));

  # execute the query
  $results = $query->execute();

  foreach ($results as $row) {
  $data[] = array($row->firstname, 
                  $row->lastname, 
                  );
  }
  $output = theme('table', 
                  array('header' => $header, 
                   'rows' => $data ));
  return $output;
}

Comment: i want to redirect page to home or somewhere...can you give me some example

Comment: One alternate would be add one menu item : $items['project_list'] = array() where you callback project_list function. And after submit, just do drupal_goto('project_list');

Comment: can u give 1 example

Comment: Okay I will write in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call the function after submit of the form.

Add this part in hook_menu:

```
function MYMODULE_menu(){

    $items['project'] = array(
    'title' => 'Project List' ,
    'page callback' => 'project_list1',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'menu_name' => 'devel',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

 return $items;

}
```

If you want the menu to appear in main menu you can make these changes:

```
     'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
     'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,



Your  function here:


  function project_list1(){
     /////code
    }
```

And then in your submit function, you can directly add:

```
  //Add this in the last line of your submit function
   drupal_goto('project');
```

This will directly go to the path 'project' and call your function

> project_list1()